# Display popup modal on browser close on community

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am using `lightning:unsavedChanges` to achieve this on community.But when I click on browser tab close, it just closes the browser and doesn't display custom `demoModal` component.
I have added below line in component

```
<lightning:unsavedChanges aura:id="unsaved"
                          onsave="{!c.handleSave}"
                          ondiscard="{!c.handleDiscard}" />
```

and in controller. Here `demoModal` is the name of component which will display modal.

```
closeEvent: function (component, event, helper){
   window.addEventListener("beforeunload", $A.getCallback(function(event){
       var unsaved = component.find("unsaved");
       unsaved.setUnsavedChanges(true, { label: 'demoModal' });
    })); 

 },
 handleSave: function(cmp, evt, helper) {

   }
 handleDiscard: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
    // similar to the handleSave method, but for discarding changes
 }
}
```

On Inspecting, I found that flow is going inside `window.addEventListener` but it does not display modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lightning:UnsavedChanges` works only in the context of console application such as closing the tabs or subtabs and not in browser close/refresh events. So, this cannot be achieved in lightning.